# How can I install vapor barrier to an exterior wall from the outside?

Tags: insulation, garage, vapor-barrier

I am insulating the garage portion of the house inside my garage. I will remove the siding and fiberboard used in the 60s. There is no insulation in the house. How do I get a vapor barrier without using spray foam? Will Tyvek work on the outside of the stud? Then, fire-rated drywall.

I live in SW  Michigan and use the AC a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Does any of the rest of the house have vapor barrier (or do you intend to install it)?

Comment: Will your wall assembly have any exterior paneling?

Comment: Michigan is a heating-dominant climate. Usually the vapor barrier is best placed on the side of the wall assembly that is more warm and humid. The purpose of vapor barrier is to control condensation that can occur when the humidity carried by warm air permeates into the insulated space and meets cooler surfaces.

Comment: For an outside wall(garage is close enough), from the inside living space you want the wall covering(drywall) vapour barrier, insulation, sheeting, house wrap, siding.  If you see the inside drywall, then vapour barrier(prefer the 6mil poly) insulation, house wrap an option, then drywall.  You want only one vapour barrier.  Applying poly from the outside is more of a PITA than from inside, you have to go around all the studs.  house wrap is water resistant, not a vapour barrier.